# Is there a legal term for the following kind of "estoppel?"

Tags: united-states, legal-terms

There is the old tale of the miscreant who killed his parents, and threw himself at the mercy of the court because he was an orphan.

"Relief" on the basis of his being an "orphan" was denied because he created the problem (by killing his parents). I believe that this is a form of estoppel.

Is there a legal term for this type of situation, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a legal term for this type of situation, and if so, what is it?

[Unclean hands](https://www.merriam-webster.com/legal/unclean%20hands).